# how to write database independent layer using Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How I can write database independent, data layer using Linq to Sql? For example I have one dbml file, which I can use with almost any database at runtime ( by specifying web.config)

Entity framwork is a better option, but it is not implemented in Mono so I can't use it.

**Edit**: I mean different databases like Sql Server, Mysql or SqlLite. I prefer to use DbLinq for other databases.

**Edit 2** :
I have created Linq to Sql mapping class by following this blog post.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/01/08/how-to-use-linq-to-sql-without-using-the-designer-generated-classes.aspx
Now how I can use this with other databases.

Comment: Do you mean different database schemas or different DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

You need a 3rd party linq provider like ALinq http://www.alinq.org/ that suports Mono.
As it is structured from Microsoft, Linq to SQL is VERY database dependent, ie it only works with MS SQL. I believe that ALinq does work on mono.  Here's a better list of 3rd party providers:
http://blog.linqexchange.com/index.php/links-to-linq-providers/

Comment: how does Alinq help me to write db independent layer?

Comment: You can write a database abstraction layer with all your queries and then simply change up the alinq connection strings and provider library references.  Alinq has porvider libraries for several different databases.  Similar to using entity framework where you simply change the reference to the appropriate library and update your connection string.